# "No protocol specified" error while trying to run forticlientsslvpn for the first time

Tags: linux, vpn, gtk

I'm trying to install forticlient on fedora 14 for vpn access, and I get the following error when I run it for the first time:

```
No protocol specified
Error: Unable to initialize gtk, is DISPLAY set properly?
```

Any ideas what could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 1):

http://hacklab.cz/2012/05/28/no-protocol-specified

It should also resolve your problem

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error whilst trying to run PgAdminIII from the command line. The reason I got this error was because I was inside an account that didn't have privileges to access gtk, an application that creates the GUI for applications.

Basically (as with most errors), try running the application as a substituted user:

```
$ sudo forticlientsslvpn
```

or change to your main account and run it:

```
$ su main_account
> password: ********
$ forticlientsslvpn
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything points to something wrong with XOrg.

- `No protocol specified` is an Xlib
  error.
- `gtk` is the GIMP Toolkit, and
  it depends on Xlib.
- `DISPLAY` is an
  environment variable used by Xlib to
  determine your display.

Do you have XOrg running? Is there something wrong with it? Can you not start other GTK apps?